# Download client over ssl but connect to arbitrary IP

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket, https

In browsers, is it possible to request javascript for a web-client over https, but have said client connect with a websocket to an IP either:

- without ssl
- with a self-signed certificate (without previously adding the certificate to the browser)

From what i read, it simply isn't. Mixed content is forbidden, and self-signed certs are not accepted, unless the user goes through a weird and dangerous looking menu, to manually accept the certificate in the browser. It's not like the typical user has the qualification to check a certificate anyways.

This would directly imply, that for this case, encryption cannot be used at all, sadly.

Isn't there something i overlooked? If the websocket connection wasn't over ssl, the client could even just encrypt itself, inside a non-ssl connection. The server it's connecting to won't have a certificate from a CA, it typically won't even have a domain.

---

Edit: some background

The desired situation is as follows:

- a user enters a website, and gets served a client via a secure connection (this is from a static domain, so having a certificate from a CA is no problem here. However, using https apparently disallows non-ssl-connections from that site, and the client accordingly).
- the client then opens a websocket connection to a server IP, which may arbitrarily vary (can even be multiple servers at the same time), and typically has no domain. For this, i can only come up with a few scenarios:

  - no ssl (forbidden, mixed content)
  - self-signed certificate, preferably the client would get the public key from the main domain, and have that pinned (self-signed produces warnings, and users can't really be required to manually install certificates just for this)
  - Some CA offers free and automated certificates for IPs, which we can depend on, and just generate new certificates whenever necessary, without any human action needed (i didn't consider this before, because i simply didn't think any CA would offer such a thing. Maybe there is, but so far, i've not encountered any)

Comment: You can set up SSL certificates for a range of domains. Your site might be `mysite.com` and a sub-domain might be `192-168-1-1.mysite.com`. Covering the entire `*.mysite.com` range would only take one certificate. See [Does each subdomain need it's own SSL certificate?](https://serverfault.com/questions/566426/does-each-subdomain-need-its-own-ssl-certificate)

Comment: The issue is, that the websocket server will not run in one location. It is a distributable program, and end-users can't be required to have certificates from a CA, nor can a certificate be shared (because it would destroy the security it offers). It would be preferable, if the client came from a secure location, but it apparently then couldn't connect to any server.

Comment: So you would have an app that isn't a browser? Then why pick websocket? Also, if you want to allow self-signed then security disappears anyway.

Comment: "isn't a browser"? The client runs in a browser, and websocket is almost unavoidable in many cases, where data is transferred back and forth, over an extended period of time, with latency in mind. Self-signed would still offer benefits over no encryption at all (plus there could be authorized certificates, just not from a CA, but this is not really in scope of the question). As mentioned, even no ssl would be fine.

Comment: Alright. The problem you're running into seems to be that of modern browser security. While websocket itself doesn't require SSL, today's browsers require it anyway for that and other things. Getting a cert should be pretty easy though even in a semi-automated way. Services like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) offer free, renewable, short-term SSL certs that browsers will accept and are automate-able.

Comment: "Let's encrypt" apparently doesn't offer certificates for IPs, and i am unaware of other CAs offering free automated certificates for such scenarios. A "normal" way would be a method to set a public key client side, for a non-CA-listed certificate, which the server would have, and the browser accepting this without a warning. However, that seems to be impossible from a browser. Perhaps webrtc isn't as ridiculous in this sense, but it would be preferable to not require that switch.

Comment: Ultimately, you need something central to act as an authority. Consider that even TOR has C&C servers that are under the creator's control, you can't just set up your own. Sure you can set up nodes and gateways, but they have no authority. Even if anybody could set up servers for your system and anonymously connect them, you'd still need some master servers under your control that have the ultimate authority. So, with Let's Encrypt, you have every server use a subdomain, authorize that subdomain with the master system, fetch their own cert for the domain, and register it with the master system

Comment: Setting subdomains for each server, and getting a certificate in an automated way might be a solution, thanks. It's at least worth considering further. However, DNS is sometimes slow to change (can take a while until it works, with a new server), and it feels kind of backwards. Yes, authority is needed. All that is why it would be best, if the client would just get the public-key from our main server, connect to whatever IP with that pinned, and the browser not throw a tantrum, because the certificate isn't from a CA. That seems to be not supported though, for whatever reasons.